# Intellij's Scala type inference differs from REPL

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-cats

I'm considering using `cats` library in my project to use its traverse/sequence feature on the list of `Either`. However, in Intellij IDEA, when I do `Show type`, I see a totally weird inferred type. At the same time, if I copy and paste this code into `sbt console`, I get nice and clean type. Here's example:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import cats._, cats.syntax.traverse._, cats.std.all._

    val xs: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2))
    val r = xs.sequenceU

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import cats._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.std.all._
xs: List[Either[String,Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2))
r: scala.util.Either[String,List[Int]] = Right(List(1, 2))
```

As you can see, the variable `r` has a nice type: `Either[String, List[Int]]`.

However, Intellij infers the following monster:

```
Unapply.Aux2Right[Applicative, Either[String, Int], Either, String, Int]#M[List[Unapply.Aux2Right[Applicative, Either[String, Int], Either, String, Int]#A]]
```

I don't want to inflict the pain of even seeing this type, left alone understanding it, on my colleagues, as it would drop my carma significantly. I've tried this with the latest Intellij 16.1 EAP and EAP build of Scala plugin, as well as with the stable versions of those, it's all the same.

I guess, there's nothing else I can do at this moment, but maybe, just maybe, there's some workaround for this?

P.S. Things like this (i.e. tooling support) slow down adoption of FP at least not less than FP's inherent conceptual complexity. :(

P.P.S. Issue in Intellij's tracker is [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10006).

Comment: InteliJ have decided the right way forward was to built their own interpreter of Scala for type inference, which also gave them the confidence that they could start Kotlin. Needles to say this is a case of learning from one's mistakes(or complete failures in this case). If you think this is bad, try using Shapeless or getting auto-complete support on Spray routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was fixed by Jetbrains. I've checked the nightly build 2.2.40 of Scala plugin [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly), and now Intellij infers the same type in the aforementioned case as REPL. Great job Jetbrains, and so quickly!

P.S. if you want to give it a try, add nightly repository to your plugins repositories list and check for updates. It's in `Settings` -> `Plugins` -> `Browse repositories...` -> `Manage repositories...`, then add the Scala plugin nightly repository: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/nightly/1347.